# How to add a new node to a dijit.Tree

Tags: dojo, tree, insertion

I want to add a new node to a dijit.ree as a sibling of the currently selected node.  I've found sample code (I'm new to dojo) that adds a new item to the tree using the newItem method of ItemFileWriteStore, but the new item always appears at the bottom of the tree.  How would I add to the store at a specified position, in particular the position corresponding to the current selection?  Pointers to sample code would be welcome :)

Thanks,
Larry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding new node to Dijit.Tree at a particular place in the tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207853/adding-new-node-to-dijit-tree-at-a-particular-place-in-the-tree)

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the parent item of current selected node and use that item as the parent of the newly created item.

```
store.newItem(itemObj, {parent : parentItem, attribute : children});
```

Normally an item in the store doesn't have a back pointer points to its parent. So you may need to maintain that yourself. For example, you can store the parent item's id in the child item and use `fetchItemByIdentity` to get the parent item.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out; here's the answer for future searchers.  Use newItem as Alex suggested.  Then use model.pasteItem to reposition the new item.  pasteItem takes a parent (selectedNode.item.parent[0]) and a position (selectedNode.getIndexInParent()+1)

Larry

Answer (score 2):

store.newItem is giving an error (Uncaught Error: dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore: Invalid attribute argument. ). Could not really find a fix for this so far and my store does not have duplicate id's.

Hence i tried using **model.newItem(newItem, parentItem)**. 
This works perfectly alright.

Thanks,
Srilatha.